# how to get message in windows phone 8.1 from Mqtt

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mqtt

I am developing a chat app in windows phone 8.1. I am using MQTT to communicate.It works fine when my app is in foreground.But I am facing two problems.

1) I am unable to get messages from sender when network is lost and reconnected.

2)I am unable to get messages from sender when I open the app which was sent in app inactive stage.

I am using this code to communicate:

```
client = new MqttClient("myhostname", 1883, false);
string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(id);
```

The above cases works fine in android am I doing wrong ?? Please help me to solve.

Thanks,

Srinivas

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, i am not getting any errors.code works fine.but i am not able get already sent message when i am connected to the internet.